# Simulating an appendable array in C...Kinda

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to write a C code that does what a chunk of python code I have written does.

I tried to keep all its lines simple, but there still turns out to be some stuff I wrote that C cannot do.

My code will take an array of coordinates and replace/add items to that array over time.

For example:

```
[[[0,1]],[[2,1],[1,14]],[[1,1]]] ==> [[[0,1]],[[2,1],[1,14],[3,2]],[[1,1]]]
```

or

```
[[[0,1]],[[2,1],[1,14]],[[1,1]]] ==> [[[0,1]],[[40]],[[1,1]]]
```

I think this is impossible in C, but how about instead using strings to represent the lists so they can be added to? Like this:

```
[['0$1$'],['2$1$1$14$'],['1$1$']] ==> [['0$1$'],['2$1$1$14$3$2'],['1$1$']]
```

and

```
[['0$1$'],['2$1$1$14$'],['1$1$']] ==> [['0$1$'],['40$'],['1$1$']]
```

In my code, I know each array in the array is either one or more pairs of numbers or just one number so this method works for me.

Can C do this and if so please provide an example.

Comment: So, do you want to append (insert at the end), or insert at a specific index?

Comment: insert at the end of one of the strings at a specific index in the array. I only need to append. so like add('hi',2,[[['0$1$'],['40$'],['1$1$']]) returns [[['0$1$'],['40$'],['1$1$hi']]

Comment: Of course it's possible in `C`. For example, as linked list of `struct`s.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm very new to C langues.

Comment: Hmm, so is this a list of coordinates or strings? 'hi' doesn't look like coordinates, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I'm trying to append a string to another when the second string is in a list.

Comment: coordinates. I was thinking of using dollar signs to differentiate them so I don't see why 'hi' is functionally different from appending '$4', sorry.

Comment: How do you implement a list in C? How do you allocate memory for the strings? The *code* in your question is not valid C, you are still thinking in Python, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm confused. You saying this can't be done? My attempt at thinking in C was using a static list instead of a dynamic one...

Comment: If you're going to be adding arbitrary amounts of appended data, then a static 'list' won't cut it. You have to use something like a linked list and have the strings allocated dynamically otherwise you're bound to run into errors.

Comment: Damn, why? That would impact reference time, won't it? Do the sizes of the strings in the array also have to be predefined?

Comment: @Jack Yes, or dynamically allocated.

Comment: Ok, could someone please link me to instructions on how to do this? I'm fairly lost.

Comment: Instructions on linked lists? If you're just now starting C and only have experience in Python is might be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: I understand the concept of a linked list. I've made such objects in python if you think that's enough.

Comment: Hold on, If I know for a fact a string can't get any larger than 256 characters, can I keep it static?

Comment: Yes, if you know it won't exceed a certain size then you can set a max size and hope it doesn't go over.

Comment: would char a[2][14]; do? I think 2 is the size of list and 14 is the size. Size in what? would a[62][256]; work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that both the length of a string and the number of said strings won't exceed a certain value, you can do this:

`char Strings[NUMBER_OF_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];  // for the null terminator`

It would then be a good practice to zero all this memory:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++)
    memset(Strings[i], 0, MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1);
```

And if you want to append a string, use `strcat`:

```
strcat(Strings[i], SourceString);
```

A safer (though *slightly* more costly since you need to call `strlen` which walks the entire string) solution would be:

```
strncat(Strings[i], SourceString, MAX_STRING_LENGTH - strlen(Strings[i]));
```